# How to sort array of objects in Java by alphabet

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, alphabetical

I have class Library

```
public class Books extends Library {
  String regNumber
  String author;
  String name;
  int yearOfPublishing;
  String publishingHouse;
  int numberOfPages;

  public Books(String regNumber, String author, String name, int yearOfPublishing,
      String publishingHouse, int numberOfPages) {
    this.regNumber = regNumber;
    this.author = author;
    this.name = name;
    this.yearOfPublishing = yearOfPublishing;
    this.publishingHouse = publishingHouse;
    this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
  }
```

How to list books with authors' last names in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should have a `Book class` for individual books.  Assuming your Library is a list of books you can then do it like this.

```
List<Book> sortedLibrary = library.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(book -> book.author))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since no details were provided about the `author` name field it sorts on the entire field whether its first, last or both names.

If you want to sort them in place, a cleaner approach would be.

```
library.sort(Comparator.comparing(book->book.author));
```